# "java.io.IOException: Class not found" on long running Streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am getting the exception below on a long running Spark Streaming application.  The exception could occur after a few minutes, but it may also may not happen for days.  This is with pretty consistent input data.

I have seen [this Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6152) but I don't think it is the same issue.  That is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` and this is `java.io.IOException: Class not found`.

My application is streaming data and writing to Parquet using Spark SQL.

I am using Spark 1.5.2.  Any ideas?

```
28-01-2016 09:36:00 ERROR JobScheduler:96 - Error generating jobs for time 1453973760000 ms
java.io.IOException: Class not found
        at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm.shaded.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getInnerClosureClasses(ClosureCleaner.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2032)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:317)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:317)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(MappedDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(MappedDStream.scala:35)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FilteredDStream.compute(FilteredDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:120)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$2.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$2.apply(JobGenerator.scala:245)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Comment: I am getting exactly the same error since past few hours. This is arising from an innocent - 'ordersPast.map{
      order => (order.pog -> order.bucket)
    }'

Comment: Good to hear that I am not alone, not an env issue.  Also very intermittent for you?  I also posted the question here in case you want to follow it: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/6601/javaioioexception-class-not-found-on-long-running.html

Comment: This has come for the first time and took me by surprise. Thanks for sharing  databricks link.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error in Spark 2.0. Were you able to address this?

Comment: No, may be good to address to the Spark mailing list if it is still happening.

Comment: I also started seeing the exact same error mapPartitionsWithIndex api from Spark 1.6 Scala 2.10.5

Comment: Prob good to tell the Spark mailing list. I'm not sure what the cause of this is...

Comment: Was there any resolution to this?

Comment: I added an answer based on my thinking. Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to post an answer to my own question. I think this happens when you start a streaming app and then remove or replace the jar file which was used in the spark-submit. Most likely the running JVM Spark Driver application tries to load some classes from a jar file that is no longer there, or has been replaced.

I don't know this to be true but I see some interest in this question so I think it is good to post my current thinking.

Comment: This is entirely possible in my case, because I did in do this when I saw the error. Moreover I had multiple spark streaming jobs that failed simultaneously which where all from the same jar. So this would really make a lot of sense.

I will rerun an confirm. Thanks!